# Angular overflow hidden isn't working and show password button also

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have implement a login page with Angular Material. The issue is that the style `overflow: hidden` and the show password button doesn't works. If if click the button twice, the webpage loads again, but it shouldn't be so. I'm very new in Angular and flexbox. Therefore it would be very helpful if everybody could explain me the issue.
Thanks a lot.

my template:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
        <form>
            <p class="spacer"></p>
            <p>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Enter your username</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <p>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
                    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
                        [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
                        <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <div class="button">
                <button type="submit" mat-button>Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

my stylesheet

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-center; /*This style isn't work*/
  overflow: hidden;/*This also*/
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px 0;
}
.mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
mat-card-title,
mat-card-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.spacer{
  height: 25px;
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AccountComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "zeiterfassung",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38", ----> here is flexbox
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Here is a Screenshot how it should look:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I will implement a login page and if the username and password is correct, the home component should be opened and should store the user ID

Comment: `flex-center` is not a valid value for [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items). `center` is... `overflow` only works when the width or height is constrained in some way.

Comment: Also `:host` is really only relevant when used with the shadow DOM. I don't see anything in your code that appears to use the shadow DOM. Perhaps you meant `:root`? I would just use `mat-card`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing the issue because you have not given type in the visibility toggle button. It should be mentioned as `type="button"`. Please check the following [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-duzjji) for working sample.

Comment: Yeah this solves the first problem. Thank you for this :) But I can't understand why the flexbox styling ```align-items: center``` doesn't works

Comment: Could it be a issue by installing flexlayout in my project ? You can see the important files in my question

Comment: You will need to specify what are you trying to center align? The mat-card? The contents inside mat-card? Login button? Are you trying to vertically center align or horizontally? Without specifying the exact thing you are trying to achieve its hard to provide a solution

Comment: Mukhjree I am triying to center the ```mat-card``` element on verticle align. I will add a screenshot how it looks like

Comment: The problem is the verticle alignment doesen't works in my project as you can see here ```align-items: flex-center```. This should make the ```mat-card``` on the center of top

Comment: Updated the link in the answer as per the design provided by you. Make sure you mark it as answer if it helps you. Code written in a short time and may contain some extra lines of code which you can go through and remove.

Comment: I will explain it you again ! The flexlayout problem is not working at the moment. I try to verticle aligning the element in the middle of the page but with ```align-items: flex-center```  that is not working. If this problem is solving, I can mark your answer :)

Comment: Okay I solved the issue. The problem was, that the container hasn't any height and therefore it can't verticle aligning

Comment: it was very nice if you could give my question a reputation, Thanks a lot for that